# Fundamental group of infinite row of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be the union of circles $C_n$ with center at $(n,0)$ and radius $1/2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show that the fundamental group of $X$ is a free group with countable generators. I think that if $Y=X \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geq 0\}$, then $X/Y$ is a wedge sum of circles and $\pi(X)$ is isomorphic to $\pi(X/Y)$. But I don't know how can I show that.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ (with the subspace topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$) can be given the structure of a CW complex.  The $0$-cells are $(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})\cap X$, and the $1$-cells are what is remaining.

The set $Y$ that you give is a CW subcomplex of $X$.  Page 11 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* says that then $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence since $A$ is contractible.  As a CW complex, $X/A$ is a wedge sum of countably many circles.  One can see this by realizing that the quotient has a single $0$-cell, and so all the $1$-cells must each contribute a circle wedge summand.

It is a general fact that the fundamental group of a graph (i.e., a CW $1$-complex) has generators in correspondence to the edges in the complement of a spanning tree, which is exactly what $Y$ happens to be.  Section 1.A in Hatcher's book has more details.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to say that I have no knowledge about the CW complex. I read Hatcher's book but I do not understand that topic very well

Comment: @KM1731 You could try creating the homotopy equivalence by hand.  You have the quotient map, and then you have to figure out a homotopy inverse, which amounts to sort of pulling each circle into $A$ so that you can deformation retract everything in $A$ to the basepoint (say at $(0,0)$).  Or you could apply the van Kampen theorem.  Let $C_0,\dots$ be each of the arcs in $X-A$, and let $X_i$ be $A\cup C_i$ for each $i$.  The fact that the amalgamating subspace $A$ is simply connected implies that the fundamental group is the free product of countably many copies of $\pi_1(X_i)=\mathbb{Z}$.